# Match "After" if it doesn't have an an -ing word after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match `After` if there isn't an `-ing` word after it (and before a comma). So there shouldn't be an `-ing` word between `After` and the comma.

Desired match (**bold**):

> After sitting down, he began to talk.
>
> After finally sitting down, he began to talk.
>
> **After he sat down,** he began to talk.

I thought this regex would do it:

```
\bAfter\b.*(?!\w+ing)+,
```

But it's also matching After if there isn't an `-ing` word after it:

> **After sitting down,** he began to talk.
>
> **After finally sitting down,** he began to talk.
>
> **After he sat down,** he began to talk.

https://regexr.com/683bv

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Please add the following to your examples: `"After, sitting down he began to talk."`, `"After, sitting down, he began to talk."` and `"After sitting down he began to talk."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

Matches only sentence from `After` and a comma, where there's no word with `-ing` after the wo

Just a lazy quantifier to the `.+` (which instead of `\w+`in your regex) does the trick

`\bAfter (?!.+?ing).*?,`

(And also a lazy quantifier after the second `.*`, just in case if there's 2 commas in the same sentence)

Output:

[image: img]

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YTyT3U/3)**

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should have added another example: `After finally sitting down,`. It shouldn't match if there are words between `After` and `-ing` either.

Comment: @alexchenco i edited my answer, check it out! and tell me if there is anymore errors

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried:

- Using `.*` will first match the whole line, then it will backtrack to match the first encountered comma, so it will also match all comma's in between.
- It can match the first encountered comma because this part `(?!\w+ing),` asserts that from the current position there are no word chars followed by `ing` and then match a `,` But `\w` does not match a comma so the asserting will always be true.

You can exclude matching a comma in the negative lookahead using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), and then also match until the first occurrence of a comma afterwards.

```
\bAfter\b(?![^,\n]*ing)[^,\n]*,
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `\bAfter\b` Match the word `After` between word boundaries
- `(?![^,\n]*ing)` Negative lookahead to assert that from the current position there is no occurrence of `ing` without crossing a comma
- `[^,\n]*,` Match optional chars except a comma (or a newline if you don't want to cross lines)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PKGnH/1)